# Remove element from Treemap via Scanner

Tags: java

I am creating a bank system project.

I want the user to be able to remove a bank account using the accountid in the scanner.
I am having trouble as when I try to move e.g. First accountid(123), second accountid(999), it will always remove the last account created.

```
/*
 * To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
 * To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */
package mainsample;
import java.util.*;
/**
 *
 * @author Khalid
 */
public class MainSample {

  /**
   * @param args the command line arguments
   */
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

    BankProcess bankProcess = new BankProcess();
    TransactionProcess transactionProcess = new TransactionProcess();


    Bank bank = new Bank();
    BankAccount bankAccount = new BankAccount();

    int input = 0;
    int selection = 0;

    while (true) {
      System.out.println("");
      System.out.println("######## MENU ########");
      System.out.println("[1] Create an account");
      System.out.println("[2] Print all existing accounts");
      System.out.println("[3] Delete an account");
      System.out.println("[4] Deposit");
      System.out.println("[5] Withdraw");
      System.out.println("[6] Print transactions");
      System.out.println("[0] Exit");
      System.out.println("######################");
      System.out.println("Please choose one of the following: ");
      selection = scan.nextInt();

      switch (selection) {

        case 0:
          System.out.println("Exit Successful");
          System.exit(0);
          break;

        case 1:
          System.out.println("'[1] Create an account' has been selected.");
          System.out.print("Account Id: ");
          int accountId = scan.nextInt();
          scan.nextLine();

          System.out.print("Holder Name: ");
          String holderName = scan.nextLine();

          System.out.print("Holder Address: ");
          String holderAddress = scan.nextLine();

          System.out.print("Opening Balance: ");
          double openingBalance = scan.nextDouble();

          System.out.print("Open Date: ");
          String openDate = scan.next();

          bankAccount = new BankAccount(accountId, holderName, openingBalance, holderAddress, openDate);
          bank.setAccounts(bankProcess.openNewAccount(bank.getAccounts(), bankAccount));

          System.out.println("Successfully Added.");
          break;

        case 2:
          System.out.println("'[2] Display all existing accounts' has been selected");
          System.out.println("-----------------------------------------------------");
          bank.getAccounts().forEach((i, b) - > System.out.println(b));
          System.out.println("-----------------------------------------------------");
          break;

        case 3:
          System.out.println("[3] Delete an account has been selected");
          System.out.println("Enter the account ID: ");
          int accountNo = scan.nextInt();
          bank.removeAccounts(bankProcess.removeAccount(bank.getAccounts(), bankAccount));
          break;

        case 4:
          System.out.println("[4] Deposit has been selected");
          System.out.println("Enter account ID: ");
          int accountNumber = scan.nextInt();

          System.out.println("Enter deposit amount: ");
          double depositAmount = scan.nextDouble();

          transactionProcess.deposit(bankAccount, depositAmount);

          System.out.println(depositAmount + " has been deposited.");
          break;

        case 5:
          System.out.println("[5] Withdraw has been selected");
          System.out.println("Enter account ID: ");
          int accountNu = scan.nextInt();

          System.out.println("Enter withdraw amount: ");
          double withdrawAmount = scan.nextDouble();

          transactionProcess.withdraw(bankAccount, withdrawAmount);

          System.out.println(withdrawAmount + " has been withdrawed.");
          break;


        case 6:
          System.out.println("[6] Print Transaction has been selected");
          System.out.println("Enter account ID: ");
          int accountN = scan.nextInt();



          break;






        default:
          System.out.println("Your choice was not valid!");

      }

    }
  }
}
```

--

```
package mainsample;
import java.util.*;
/**
 *
 * @author Khalid
 */
public class Bank {

  private TreeMap < Integer, BankAccount > bankAccounts = new TreeMap < Integer, BankAccount > ();



  public TreeMap < Integer, BankAccount > getAccounts() {
    return bankAccounts;
  }
  public void setAccounts(TreeMap < Integer, BankAccount > accounts) {
    this.bankAccounts = accounts;
  }

  public BankAccount getAccount(Integer accountNumber) {
    return bankAccounts.get(accountNumber);
  }

  public void removeAccounts(TreeMap < Integer, BankAccount > accounts) {
    this.bankAccounts = accounts;
  }
}
```

--

```
/*
 * To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
 * To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */
package mainsample;
import java.util.*;
/**
 *
 * @author Khalid
 */
public class BankAccount {
  private int accountId;
  private String holderName;
  private String holderAddress;
  private String openDate;
  private double currentBalance;

  private List < Transaction > transactions = new ArrayList < Transaction > ();

  //Provide Blank Constructor
  public BankAccount() {}

  //Constructor with an arguments.
  public BankAccount(int accountNum, String holderNam, double currentBalance, String holderAdd, String openDate) {
    this.accountId = accountNum;
    this.holderName = holderNam;
    this.holderAddress = holderAdd;
    this.openDate = openDate;
    this.currentBalance = currentBalance;
  }

  // Always Provide Setter and Getters
  public int getAccountId() {
    return accountId;
  }
  public void setAccountId(int accountId) {
    this.accountId = accountId;
  }
  public String getHolderName() {
    return holderName;
  }
  public void setHolderName(String holderName) {
    this.holderName = holderName;
  }
  public String getHolderAddress() {
    return holderAddress;
  }
  public void setHolderAddress(String holderAddress) {
    this.holderAddress = holderAddress;
  }
  public String getOpenDate() {
    return openDate;
  }
  public void setOpenDate(String openDate) {
    this.openDate = openDate;
  }
  public double getCurrentBalance() {
    return currentBalance;
  }
  public void setCurrentBalance(double currentBalance) {
    this.currentBalance = currentBalance;
  }

  public List < Transaction > getTransactions() {
    return transactions;
  }

  public void setTransactions(List < Transaction > transactions) {
    this.transactions = transactions;
  }

  public String toString() {
    return "\nAccount number: " + accountId + "\nHolder's name: " + holderName + "\nHolder's address: " + holderAddress + "\nOpen Date: " + openDate + "\nCurrent balance: " + currentBalance;
  }
}
```

--

```
import java.util.*;
/**
 *
 * @author Khalid
 */
public class BankProcess {
    // return the  Updated list of BankAccounts
    public TreeMap<Integer,BankAccount> openNewAccount(TreeMap<Integer,BankAccount> bankAccounts,BankAccount bankAccount) {
        //Get the List of existing bank Accounts then add the new BankAccount to it.
        bankAccounts.put(bankAccount.getAccountId(), bankAccount);
        return bankAccounts;
    }

    public TreeMap<Integer,BankAccount> removeAccount(TreeMap<Integer,BankAccount> bankAccounts,BankAccount bankAccount) {
      bankAccounts.remove(bankAccount.getAccountId(), bankAccount);
        return bankAccounts;  
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you sure your `BankProcess` class compiles?  The `remove` method of the `TreeMap` class has one parameter, not two.

Comment: Yes, it compiles with no problem. However, it doesn't work the way I want it to.

Comment: Well, the code you've shown here _doesn't_ compile, so maybe it would be better if you make sure you copy and paste it accurately.

Comment: ok. I've pasted in the latest. It compiles in NetBeans

Comment: For the future, don't use the code snippet tag for Java. Just indent it and it'll be formatted as code.

Comment: No,  your `BankProcess` class here still doesn't compile.  I haven't checked the other classes.

Comment: Maybe because the BankProcess relies on other classes.

Comment: Because you're calling the `remove` method of `TreeMap` incorrectly, as I explained in an earlier comment.

Comment: I tried to create a remove method following the openNewAccount method. I wanted to try before I see for help. I know it's completely wrong.

Answer (score 0):

The simple solution to your problem is that you simply never compute what account to remove.

From your case 3:

```
int accountNo = scan.nextInt();
bank.removeAccounts(bankProcess.removeAccount(bank.getAccounts(), bankAccount));
break;
```

You get the account number accountNo from the command line and then you do exactly nothing with it. You just call removeAccount with the value bankAccount has last been set to. And since you surely added some account before that, you just remove the account that you added at last.

For those that wonder why this compiles:

The Map interface defines a remove(Object, Object) method since Java 8, see here: [java.util.Map#remove(Object, Object)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Map.html#remove-java.lang.Object-java.lang.Object-)

It basically ensures that a key is only then removed from the map, if it has got the given value.